# files exported from Photoshop always register as changed in git

Tags: git, png, photoshop

I'm working on an iOS app with a fair number of PNG files that I export via Photoshop's slices and "Save for Web" features. In many cases, a single export will generate a large number of PNGs, of which only one has actually changed. Yet my **git repository registers every single exported file as changed**. I've tried turning off metadata in Save for Web but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any idea how I might avoid this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check (for example with a hashing function) that files really didn't change ? Normally git compares the SHA1 hashs.

Answer (score 2):

There is a section in the [ProGit Book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) that specifically deals with comparing binary files that should help you.  The bit referring to image files is about halfway down the page I linked to.

The method suggested there requires you to download the [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and configure git to use that to diff your .png files, but I suspect it would need you to turn saving of the metadata back on.  I don't know if that is an option for you?